Unity TextMeshPro, text box's image shadow
I am not using button but instead I am using TextMeshPro for making the buttons structure and had used a image(having neon borders) in the text area. If anyone can help with it.
I tried editing the sprite image which i used in the text area but no effect of that.
I want to have a curve of the neon shadow(either it is blue or orange) around the corners of my text box which is currenlty rectangle.
I have also attached a image for your reference click on the title.
